# Here Maps iOS premium SDK NMAMAPGestureDelegate makes app freezing

Tags: here-api

We are facing an issue on the here maps iOS premium SDK:

Has someone already faced their map freezing or going extremely slow  (like unusuable) after using NMAMAPGestureDelegate protocole either on virtual or real device ?
Any idea about why we are facing this issue ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please mention the ios Version, ide version and the mobile version you are using.

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport we've created an issue on the github repos (https://github.com/heremaps/here-ios-sdk-examples/issues/91) where we gave details, tested on both xcode 9.2 and xcode 10

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade to latest IOS version SDK that has significantly improved the performance issues.

The following highlights give a short summary of the most important changes, added functionality, and improvements:

SDK Starter edition Version 3.14 is deprecated. Only critical defects will be fixed in future releases.
Added support for new devices: iPhone 11, iPhone 11 Pro, iPhone 11 Pro Max, iPad 7